# Cannot get client IPAddress after hosting .net core with docker

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

I had tried to use the following code:

```
 app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
          ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
```

Either  `Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].ToString()` or `Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` cannot retrieve client IP Address instead getting ::ffff:172.18.0.1. Anyone can help?

Comment: This might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already put ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor and ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto. Why still not able to get the client ip address?

Comment: Did you add app.UseForwardedHeaders() in the Configure part?

Comment: yup..i put it before app.UseHttpsRedirection(). Any thing I missed out?